# Using the presence feature in react redux firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

[Picture of react redux firebase documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZdZQ.png)

I see how they included the presence parameter in the rrfConfig. Does this mean I need to create a presence collection on cloud firestore. Also, how would I actually implement this in react so that I can retrieve the online status of users. I am confused on how to structure this in my react project. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence feature in `react-redux-firebase` wraps the similar feature in the Firebase Realtime Database, which depends on this database's web socket nature. This feature is not natively available in Cloud Firestore, due to the complete different (and connectionless) wire protocol that Firestore uses.

So you'll need to either use Realtime Database to use this feature in `react-redux-firebase`, or wrap it in Cloud Firestore as shown in the Firebase documentation on [implementing presence in Firestore with Cloud Functions and Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).